# Are there any known cameo appearances in “The Last Jedi”?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, cameo

In *The Force Awakens* Daniel Craig (James Bond) played a cameo appearance as a storm trooper, for example. Are there any other cameos known for *The Last Jedi*?  I thought I heard Price William & Harry (UK) both played storm troopers in *The Last Jedi*, but it was on TV and I wasn’t paying attention, so I could be mistaken.

Any news on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ones I noticed while watching:

- Gareth Edwards (director of *Rogue One*) plays a resistance trooper on Crait (the red/white planet at the end of the movie). He's standing next to the trooper that says "Salt".
- Not so much a cameo, but well-known UK comedian Adrian Edmondson plays Hux's second-in-command. From [here](https://www.fanthatracks.com/news/film-music-tv/adrian-edmondson-vyvyan-young-ones-last-jedi/), quoting the Press Association:

  > Johnson said he was particularly excited to bring The Young Ones star Adrian Edmondson on to the set. He said: “Because I’m a huge fan of The Young Ones and Bottom we had Adrian Edmondson play a part as a First Order Officer and I was kind of geeking out about that...”

[This page](http://fandom.wikia.com/articles/the-last-jedi-all-the-cameos-and-easter-eggs-we-spotted) lists a bunch of others:

- Tom Hardy, Gary Barlow and Princes William and Harry play stormtroopers, although there is dispute as to which of these scenes ended-up in the movie
- Joseph Gordon Levitt has a voice credit.
- Mark Hamill's two sons, Nathan and Griffin, appear in the scenes on Crait.
- Justin Theroux plays the master codebreaker on Canto Bight.
- Lily Cole is the woman standing next to him at the gambling table.
- Directors Edgar Wright and Joe Cornish apparently have cameos also.

Comment: Warwick Davis is also at the casinos in Canto Bight, [source](https://www.thewrap.com/star-wars-the-last-jedi-8-a-list-cameos-to-keep-an-eye-and-ear-out-for-photos/)

Answer (score 3):

Per [this Screenrant article](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-last-jedi-celebrity-cameos/)

- Tom Hardy, Prince William, Prince Harry and Gary Barlow play storm troopers. Hardy's trooper has a verbal exchange with Finn
- Joseph Gordon-Levitt and Noah Segan are in as director Rian Johnson's regulars ([per this tweet](https://twitter.com/hitRECordJoe/status/917858563913007106))

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that

> Yoda turning up out the blue

counts as a cameo

> a small character part in a play or film, played by a distinguished actor.

Comment: Voiced by Frank Oz (who retired in 2000) moreover!